# navigating through records on a database

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Simplest way how to loop and display through records using textbox, combo box and datetimepicker.

Below is a code but still cant figure it out

```
Dim dr As DataRow
Dim ds As Dataset
Dim dt As DataTable
<code to fill the dataset>
dt = ds.Tables(0)
For Each dr In dt.Rows
Console.WriteLine (dr("ColName"))
Next
ds.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two loops to do this - an outer loop for the number of rows in the table, and an inner loop for the columns in each row.

You have the For Each for the rows already, but you need to know how many columns are in the `DataRow`, and print out the value in each column.  You can get the count of columns from the `DataTable`.

```
Dim cols As Integer

cols = dt.Columns.Count - 1

For Each dr in dt.Rows
    For i As Integer = 0 To cols        
        Console.WriteLine(dr(i).ToString())
    Next
Next
```

Notice that I call `ToString()` on the value returned from each column, and reference the column by it's ordinal.  When you access a specific column in the DataRow, it returns an `Object`, so you'll need to cast that value to the correct data type for use in your program.

The code you posted would have only printed the value for the column that had "ColName" as it's column name for each row.  If you didn't have a column named "ColName" then you would see an error.

Comment: sir can we chat so i can understand more using this code i need it to navigate through my records its the only thing missing in my system for a back and next record button

Comment: @ivandinglasan - I'm not sure how to set up a chat room on SO and invite you. What's your ultimate goal when you say "navigate through records"?

Comment: @ivandinglasan - your email address bounced.  You can e-mail me - my e-mail address is on my profile page.